# Angular Call NGIF inside custom directive

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I'm looking to use NGIF inside my own directive as a kind of wrapper.

I found the following example which is working perfectly...

```
var NAME = 'yourCustomIf';

angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive(NAME, function (ngIfDirective) {
    console.log(ngIfDirective)

    var ngIf = ngIfDirective[0];

    return {
        transclude: ngIf.transclude,
        priority: ngIf.priority,
        terminal: ngIf.terminal,
        restrict: ngIf.restrict,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            var value = $attr[NAME];
            var yourCustomValue = $scope.$eval(value);

            $attr.ngIf = function () {
                return yourCustomValue;
            };


            ngIf.link.apply(ngIf, arguments);
        }
    };

});
```

The problem is I don't know how to convert this to typescript. Here's what I have so far...

```
export class MyCustomDirective implements ng.IDirective {

    constructor(private ngIfDirective: ng.IDirective) {

    }

    transclude = this.ngIfDirective.transclude;
    priority = this.ngIfDirective.priority;
    terminal = this.ngIfDirective.terminal;
    restrict = this.ngIfDirective.restrict;

    link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ctrl: any) => {

        var atrribute = attrs["custom"];

        var value = scope.$eval(atrribute);

        attrs["ngIf"] = () => {
            return value;
        };


    }

}
```

My problem is with the last line `ngIf.link.apply(ngIf, arguments);`. There is no apply method here.

Comment: What exactly is your desired end result?
The snippet you found it very hacky and there is probably a much cleaner way to do what your want. That code above is digging deep into the underlying framework, making assumptions about it, and trying to knit it into something else entirely.

Comment: Basically I want to create my own my my if directive. My directive is going to talk to an angular service to determine the outcome. I thought it would be easier and future proof to create a wrapper around ngif directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot recommend extending directive. There is not a good way to do it and the way each directive handles templates, transclusion, and scopes will be different and not likely to mesh.

If you want to wrap a directive I would recommend using transclusion and using the directive as normal.

```
module.directive('specialIf', function (myService) {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<ng-transclude ng-if="isShown"></ng-transclude>'
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.isShown = myService.isShown();
        }
    };

});
```

Your usage would then look like:

```
<special-if>
    <div>Stuff I may or may not want showing up</div>
</special-if>
```

Comment: I ended up going down this route. It was a lot easier to convert to Typescript. Thank you